# About a measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set with $m(A)=8$. How to show that there exists a measurable set $B\subset A$ such that $m(B)=5$?

I am not getting any idea how to proceed? Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $f(x):=m(A\cap(-\infty,x])$. This function is continuous (why?), $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$, and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=8$.

Comment: Please explain it a little more...I am still unable to make it out.

Comment: Yeah, I have got it. Using intermediate value theorem we can always get $c\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(c)=5$.